# How to get the data out of `requests.Response` object in Python?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, binance, cryptocurrency

- I am downloading data from the cryptocurrency exchange [dydx](https://dydx.exchange/).
- The example URL of REST API endpoint that I am dealing with is https://api.dydx.exchange/v3/historical-funding/BTC-USD (You can check out the [API document of the API endpoint](https://docs.dydx.exchange/?python#get-historical-funding) as well)
- Since there is a [Python library provided by dydx](https://github.com/dydxprotocol/dydx-v3-python), I used the Python codes to download data from the API endpoint mentioned above. However, the answer that I receive after downloading the data is just `<dydx3.helpers.requests.Response at 0x1880b5a02b0>`.
- To see the content of the `requests.Response` object, I used the method `.text`. However the output is an error message saying `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'text'`
- `.json()` also does not work, as the output says `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'json'`
- The Python code that I used is provided below.
- **How can I get the same data of this URL https://api.dydx.exchange/v3/historical-funding/BTC-USD by using Python?**

```
from dydx3.helpers.request_helpers import generate_query_path
from dydx3.helpers.requests import request

class Public(object):

    def __init__(
        self,
        host,
    ):
        self.host = host

    # ============ Request Helpers ============

    def _get(self, request_path, params={}):
        return request(
            generate_query_path(self.host + request_path, params),
            'get',
        )

    def _put(self, endpoint, data):
        return request(
            self.host + '/v3/' + endpoint,
            'put',
            {},
            data,
        )

    # ============ Requests ============

    def get_historical_funding(self, market, effective_before_or_at=None):
        '''
        Get historical funding for a market
        :param market: required
        :type market: str in list [
            "BTC-USD",
            "ETH-USD",
            "LINK-USD",
            ...
        ]
        :param effective_before_or_at: optional
        :type effective_before_or_at: str
        :returns: Array of historical funding for a specific market
        :raises: DydxAPIError
        '''
        uri = '/'.join(['/v3/historical-funding', market])
        return self._get(
            uri,
            {'effectiveBeforeOrAt': effective_before_or_at},
        )

client = Public(host="https://api.dydx.exchange")
data = client.get_historical_funding("BTC-USD")

data
>>> <dydx3.helpers.requests.Response at 0x1880b5a02b0>

data.text
>>> AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'text'
```

- I initialized the client with `host="https://api.dydx.exchange"`, because according to the [API document](https://docs.dydx.exchange/?python#client-initialization), host is the base URL of API endpoints.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible they just put a wrapper around the requests package? If so, all the functionality of the requests package and Response object should still be available.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response), it seems you can use `data.json` to get the data in json format.

Comment: @Kroshtan I used the `client.get_historical_funding("BTC-USD").text` and the output is an error message, saying `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'text'`. Any advice, please?

Comment: @Kroshtan `client.get_historical_funding("BTC-USD").json()` also gives me the error message saying `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'json'`

Comment: This is not the `requests` library. This is a submodule of some other package. `dydx3.helpers.requests.Response` has nothing to do with `requests.Response`.

Comment: It looks like the data you're looking for would be in the `data` attribute of this object, judging by the [source code](https://github.com/dydxprotocol/dydx-v3-python/blob/master/dydx3/helpers/requests.py).

Answer (score 0):

The source code for this library shows two returned attributes:
`data` and `headers`

Answer (score 0):

The naming used in the `dydx3` library is a bit confusing, `dydx3.helpers.requests` is not the `requests` module.

The `dydx3.helpers.requests.Response` object only has 2 attributes:

- `headers` which contains the HTTP headers of the response from the API
- `data` which contains a `dict` either empty or containing the json data returned by the API.

So all you have to do in your code to get the data is:

```py
from dydx3.helpers.request_helpers import generate_query_path
from dydx3.helpers.requests import request

class Public(object):

    def __init__(
        self,
        host,
    ):
        self.host = host

    # ============ Request Helpers ============

    def _get(self, request_path, params={}):
        return request(
            generate_query_path(self.host + request_path, params),
            'get',
        )

    def _put(self, endpoint, data):
        return request(
            self.host + '/v3/' + endpoint,
            'put',
            {},
            data,
        )

    # ============ Requests ============

    def get_historical_funding(self, market, effective_before_or_at=None):
        '''
        Get historical funding for a market
        :param market: required
        :type market: str in list [
            "BTC-USD",
            "ETH-USD",
            "LINK-USD",
            ...
        ]
        :param effective_before_or_at: optional
        :type effective_before_or_at: str
        :returns: Array of historical funding for a specific market
        :raises: DydxAPIError
        '''
        uri = '/'.join(['/v3/historical-funding', market])
        return self._get(
            uri,
            {'effectiveBeforeOrAt': effective_before_or_at},
        ).data  # CHANGE MADE HERE
```